# maven does not change the snapshot jar file in local repository

Tags: maven

We config jfrog artifactory successfully and create a pom.xml to build and deploy our basic jar files into it as snapshot. then we configure another project to get those jar files from repository and it did successfully too, then we try to change basic libraries and deploy it again as the same snapshot name, and it did correctly but when we want to get those libraries again, maven does not change the basic libraries in local repository, unless we change the version of the snapshot but we don't want to do it.

deploy pom.xml configuration file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jfrog.buildinfo</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactory-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-info</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>publish</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <deployProperties>
                                <gradle>awesome</gradle>
                            </deployProperties>
                            <artifactory>
                                <includeEnvVars>true</includeEnvVars>
                                <timeoutSec>60</timeoutSec>
                                <propertiesFile>publish.properties</propertiesFile>
                            </artifactory>
                            <publisher>
                                <contextUrl>{{ARTIFACTORY_CONTEXT_URL|"http://tls.local:9081/artifactory"}}</contextUrl>
                                <username>admin</username>
                                <password>AP5PqkrxgwKVMBeY6wxPYr66R3M</password>
                                <excludePatterns>*-tests.jar</excludePatterns>
                                <repoKey>libs-release-local</repoKey>
                                <snapshotRepoKey>libs-snapshot-local</snapshotRepoKey>
                            </publisher>
                            <buildInfo>
                                <buildName>plugin-demo</buildName>
                                <buildNumber>{{DRONE_BUILD_NUMBER|TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER|CI_BUILD_NUMBER|BUILD_NUMBER}}
                                </buildNumber>
                                <buildUrl>{{DRONE_BUILD_URL|CI_BUILD_URL|BUILD_URL}}</buildUrl>
                            </buildInfo>
                            <licenses>
                                <autoDiscover>true</autoDiscover>
                                <includePublishedArtifacts>false</includePublishedArtifacts>
                                <runChecks>true</runChecks>
                                <scopes>compile,runtime</scopes>
                                <violationRecipients>build@organisation.com</violationRecipients>
                            </licenses>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

third party pom.xml configuration file:

```
 <repository>           
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://tls.local:9081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

How can we achieve our goal?

Comment: Have you tried to use `mvn -U ...` ?

Comment: technically we use intellij, right click on the pox.xml click maven then click reimport but when we want to run maven by command we use mvn -U clean deploy or mvn -U clean install but none of them replace the old one with new one

Comment: we got it , fist we must configure our jfrog  repository's maven snapshot version behavior to unique and check handle releases and handle snapshot and then delete completely our local repository's snapshot.

Comment: Glad to see you solved it. Please add your comment as answer to your question so other people can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first we must configure our jfrog repository's maven snapshot version behavior to unique and check handle releases and handle snapshot and then delete completely our local repository's snapshot